# Find relational records on joins through joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To give a brief overview, I have a course system with models instructor, course types, and materials. There are two joins (has_many through) tables for each instructor to connect to types (instructor_types) and for types to connect to materials (material_types).

instructor_types table example:

```
id, type_id, instructor_id
1,  2,       1
2,  3,       1
```

material_types table example:

```
id, material_id, type_id
1,  1,           2
2,  2,           2
```

The instructor's who's ids are in the instructor_types table should only be able to find material records which align with the type_id in material_types table.

I've tried (in the material.rb model):

```
has_many :material_types, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :types, through: :material_types

def self.list_type_permissions(instructor) #current instructor id
@materials = self.joins(:material_types).where('type_id = ?', instructor.types)
end
```

which produces mysql error

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `types`.* FROM `types` INNER JOIN `instructor_types` ON `types`.`id` = `i' at line 1: SELECT `materials`.* FROM `materials` INNER JOIN `material_types` ON `material_types`.`material_id` = `materials`.`id` WHERE (type_id = SELECT `types`.* FROM `types` INNER JOIN `instructor_types` ON `types`.`id` = `instructor_types`.`type_id` WHERE `instructor_types`.`instructor_id` = 1)
```

of which I'm trying to render in the view the records simply in a loop:

```
<% @materials.each do |material| %>
<li><%= material.title %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're accessing the `type_id` filed on the `material_types` table, you have to specify it in the AR query. Try this:

```
joins(:material_types).where(material_types: { type_id: instructor.type_ids })
```

You can drop the instance variable (unless you are memoizing) and the `self`.